# Prove the function $f(x,y)=3x^2y-xy^2.$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the function $f(x,y)=3x^2y-xy^2.$ is differentiable.

I was thinking in prove this:

$lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow \bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})||}{||\bar{h}||}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

And this:

$lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow \bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{x})||}{||\bar{h}||}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

But i don't sure of how proceed with this type of exercise! can someone help me?

Comment: Why not just write down its partial derivatives and note that they're continuous everywhere?

Comment: you say calculate the partial derivatives in $x$ and $y$ and see is continuous? @GTonyJacobs

Comment: Yes; if you can write down the derivative of a function, then it is differentiable.

Comment: You should probably ask your professor what theorems you're allowed to assume. That polynomials are differentiable is a basic finding in real analysis, and that this is differentiable follows trivially from that.

Answer (score 0):

The partial derivatives are continuous (they are polynomials), then the Jacobian is of the form $\left[\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}~~\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]$ and satisfies the differential condition.